# Removing Aged IP Blocks From CloudFlare with CloudFlare API and PHP

Tags: php, firewall, cloudflare

I'd like to periodically clean up the IP address blocks set up in a CloudFlare account which are older than (say) a month.

I can of course download, using the API, the entire list of all existing IP blocks and then parse that for any block added before the cut-off date.

I've started to code this in PHP and am realising it's quite a task. Before I proceed down this road, is there a way to do this in a single API call.

Or is there some other way to simplify this process?

TY!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found some PHP code and explanation on how to do this here:

http://www.aetherweb.co.uk/automatically-expiring-cloudflare-ip-blocks-by-age/

Pasting code verbatim:

```
// Read in all existing CloudFlare IP blocks then delete 
// all which are older than some specified value

$authemail = "your_cloudflare@email_address.com";
$authkey   = "your_cloudflare_auth_key";
$page      = 1;
$ids       = array(); // id's to block
$cutoff    = time()-(3600*24*28); // 28 days

while(1)
{
    $ch = curl_init("https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/user/firewall/access_rules/rules?mode=block&configuration_target=ip&page=$page&per_page=10&order=created_on&direction=asc&match=all");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'X-Auth-Email: '.$authemail,
        'X-Auth-Key: '.$authkey,
        'Content-Type: application/json'
        ));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    $r = json_decode($response, true);

    $result = $r['result'];

    // Scan for results which were created BEFORE $cutoff
    foreach ($result as $block)
    {
        // Only remove 'block' type rules
        // And not if 'donotexpire' is in the notes
        // for the rule
        if (($block['mode'] == 'block') and (!preg_match("/donotexpire/is",$block['notes'])))
        {
            $blocktime = strtotime($block['created_on']);
            if ($blocktime <= $cutoff)
            {
                $ids[] = $block['id'];
            }
        }
    }

    $info   = $r['result_info'];
    // Result info tells us how many pages in total there are
    $page++;
    if ($info['total_pages'] < $page)
    {
        break;
    }
}

$log = '';

foreach ($ids as $id)
{
    // Delete this rule
    $ch = curl_init("https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/user/firewall/access_rules/rules/$id");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'X-Auth-Email: '.$authemail,
        'X-Auth-Key: '.$authkey,
        'Content-Type: application/json'
        ));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'DELETE');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    $log .= $response . "\n";
}

if (sizeof($ids)>0)
{
    mail($authemail, "CF UNBLOCK REPORT " . date('r'), $log);
}
```